# How would I make this collide with 2D objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm working on a 2D platformer, and I was using a player physics script, it seems to not collide with 2D objects (that have 2D colliders.) I would like to know how to make it collide with 2D objects, I'm not familiar with 2D collsions and such.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


[RequireComponent (typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class PlayerPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask collisionMask;

    private BoxCollider collider;
    private Vector3 s;
    private Vector3 c;

    private Vector3 originalSize;
    private Vector3 originalCentre;
    private float colliderScale;

    private int collisionDivisionsX = 3;
    private int collisionDivisionsY =10;

    private float skin = .005f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool grounded;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool movementStopped;

    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;

    void Start() {
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
        colliderScale = transform.localScale.x;

        originalSize = collider.size;
        originalCentre = collider.center;
        SetCollider(originalSize,originalCentre);
    }

    public void Move(Vector2 moveAmount) {

        float deltaY = moveAmount.y;
        float deltaX = moveAmount.x;
        Vector2 p = transform.position;

        grounded = false;

        for (int i = 0; i<collisionDivisionsX; i ++) {
            float dir = Mathf.Sign(deltaY);
            float x = (p.x + c.x - s.x/2) + s.x/(collisionDivisionsX-1) * i;
            float y = p.y + c.y + s.y/2 * dir;

            ray = new Ray(new Vector2(x,y), new Vector2(0,dir));
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,Mathf.Abs(deltaY) + skin,collisionMask)) {
                float dst = Vector3.Distance (ray.origin, hit.point);

                if (dst > skin) {
                    deltaY = dst * dir - skin * dir;
                }
                else {
                    deltaY = 0;
                }

                grounded = true;

                break;

            }
        }


        // Check collisions left and right
        movementStopped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i<collisionDivisionsY; i ++) {
            float dir = Mathf.Sign(deltaX);
            float x = p.x + c.x + s.x/2 * dir;
            float y = p.y + c.y - s.y/2 + s.y/(collisionDivisionsY-1) * i;

            ray = new Ray(new Vector2(x,y), new Vector2(dir,0));
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,Mathf.Abs(deltaX) + skin,collisionMask)) {
                float dst = Vector3.Distance (ray.origin, hit.point);

                if (dst > skin) {
                    deltaX = dst * dir - skin * dir;
                }
                else {
                    deltaX = 0;
                }

                movementStopped = true;
                break;

            }
        }

        if (!grounded && !movementStopped) {
            Vector3 playerDir = new Vector3(deltaX,deltaY);
            Vector3 o = new Vector3(p.x + c.x + s.x/2 * Mathf.Sign(deltaX),p.y + c.y + s.y/2 * Mathf.Sign(deltaY));
            ray = new Ray(o,playerDir.normalized);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray,Mathf.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY),collisionMask)) {
                grounded = true;
                deltaY = 0;
            }
        }


        Vector2 finalTransform = new Vector2(deltaX,deltaY);

        transform.Translate(finalTransform,Space.World);
    }

    public void SetCollider(Vector3 size, Vector3 centre) {
        collider.size = size;
        collider.center = centre;

        s = size * colliderScale;
        c = centre * colliderScale;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do both objects have rigidbody components?

Comment: I added rigid bodies, it seems to work (except for the player clipping through the floor after a few seconds?)

Comment: In the future I would recommend you put questions like this in the gamedev stack exchange.